# how to make non blocking call in php

Tags: php, curl, exec

I am using a php script to upload lot of files. I am using the CURL command . The remote server accepts only POST requests. But when I execute the below script it processes the first request and waits until the first file is uploaded. Is there a way to make it non blocking and run simultaneous 2 curl upload requests .Find the code sample below.

```
<?php
  $arr= array(somefile1.txt,somefile2.txt);
  for ( $i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
     $cmd = "curl  -F name=aaa -F type=yyy  FileName=@/xxxxx/xxxx/$arr[$i] http://someurl.com";
     print "Executing file ";
     shell_exec("nohup  $cmd  2> /dev/null & echo $!" );
     print "=======  done ================";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good article about "multithreading", take a look at it here: [Multithreading in PHP with CURL](https://web.archive.org/web/20091014034235/http://www.ibuildings.co.uk/blog/archives/811-Multithreading-in-PHP-with-CURL.html)

Comment: Don't just post link-only answers. Summarize the link in case it becomes a dead link.
Also, I wouldn't call that multithreading. It is just multiple curl requests fired by the curl library.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you may want [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php).  Here is an outbound example; it will have to be adapted for your inbound problem.  This seems cleaner than you forking multiple threads yourself.

```
<?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use PHP Simple Curl Wrapper - https://github.com/Graceas/php-simple-curl-wrapper. This library allows the processing of multiple request's asynchronously.

You can find full answer here: [php asynchronous cURL request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800669/php-asynchronous-curl-request/68515605#68515605)

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot run simultaneously two curl statements.

Curl is made for working like this. A Curl statement will make the later statements
wait until it finishes its operation.