# Async curl request in PHP

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, request

I'm executing two curl post requests in PHP. Here's how they look like:

```
//Onfleet API credentials 
$username = 'xxxxx'; 
$api_onfleet = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';    
$url_onfleet = "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);
    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // obtain response
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);


     // Post the Pickup task to Onfleet
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_onfleet);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_onfleet);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"destination":{"address":{"unparsed":"'.$pickup_address.'"},"notes":"'.$comments.'"},"recipients":[{"name":"'.$name.'","phone":"+61'.$phone.'","notes":"Number of riders: '.$riders.'"}],"completeBefore":'.$timestamp.',"pickupTask":"yes","autoAssign":{"mode":"distance"}}');

    $result_pickup = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Post the Dropoff task to Onfleet
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_onfleet);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_onfleet);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"destination":{"address":{"unparsed":"'.$dropoff_address.'"},"notes":"'.$comments.'"},"recipients":[{"name":"'.$name.'","phone":"+61'.$phone.'","notes":"Number of riders: '.$riders.'"}],"autoAssign":{"mode":"distance"}}');

    $result_dropoff = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

They are working, but sometimes, the second curl post request is not executed.

I'd like to execute this two requests at the same time.

How can I do that? Please note that they take different options in the postfields.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73917317/14344959 for Simultaneous cURL requests using curl_multi_exec in PHP

Answer (score 70, accepted):

So what you want to do is asynchronous execution of the cUrl Requests.

So you would need a asynchronous/parallel processing library for php.

---

## Async cURL

The other way is to use the built in [asynchronous cURL functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php).

So, when using `curl_multi_*`, your code would look something like:

```
$username = 'xxxxx'; 
$api_onfleet = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';    
$url_onfleet = "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);
    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


     // Post the Pickup task to Onfleet
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_onfleet);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_onfleet);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"destination":{"address":{"unparsed":"'.$pickup_address.'"},"notes":"'.$comments.'"},"recipients":[{"name":"'.$name.'","phone":"+61'.$phone.'","notes":"Number of riders: '.$riders.'"}],"completeBefore":'.$timestamp.',"pickupTask":"yes","autoAssign":{"mode":"distance"}}');
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$session);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Suggested Reading:

1. [`curl_multi_init()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)
2. [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)
3. [`curl_multi_add_handle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php)
4. [`curl_multi_remove_handle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-remove-handle.php)

---

## pThreads

One of the prominent threading libraries for php is [`pthreads`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)

You would need to first get the dll/so file and save it in the `php/ext` dir, and enable that extension in `php.ini`.

After That, this code would do your job:

```
class Request1 extends Thread {
    $username = 'xxxxx'; 
    $api_onfleet = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';    
    $url_onfleet = "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks";
    public function run() {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
        $request =  $this->url.'api/mail.send.json';
    
        // Generate curl request
        $session = curl_init($request);
        // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
        curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
       curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
       // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
       curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // obtain response
        $response = curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session);
    }
}


class Request2 extends Thread {
    $username = 'xxxxx'; 
    $api_onfleet = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';    
    $url_onfleet = "https://onfleet.com/api/v2/tasks";
    public function run() {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_onfleet);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->api_onfleet);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");  
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"destination":{"address":{"unparsed":"'.$pickup_address.'"},"notes":"'.$comments.'"},"recipients":[{"name":"'.$name.'","phone":"+61'.$phone.'","notes":"Number of riders: '.$riders.'"}],"completeBefore":'.$timestamp.',"pickupTask":"yes","autoAssign":{"mode":"distance"}}');

      $result_pickup = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);

      // Post the Dropoff task to Onfleet
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url_onfleet);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->api_onfleet);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");  
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"destination":{"address":{"unparsed":"'.$dropoff_address.'"},"notes":"'.$comments.'"},"recipients":[{"name":"'.$name.'","phone":"+61'.$phone.'","notes":"Number of riders: '.$riders.'"}],"autoAssign":{"mode":"distance"}}');

      $result_dropoff = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
    }
}

$req1 = new Request1();
$req1->start();
$req2 = new Request2();
$req2->start();
```

So, basically you need to create a class which extends the `Thread` class and everything you want to run asynchronously (rather parallely), would be put in the function `run()` of the class.

When you want to start the thread just instantiate the class in a variable, and call the start method of the object, like `$threadsObject->start()` and everything in the `run()` would be executed on another thread.

Reference:

1. [`class::Thread`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php)
2. [`Thread::start`](http://php.net/manual/en/thread.start.php)

That's it.

Comment: おかげでたくさん、埼玉さん！Really helpful )

Comment: Finally someone explaining how to do this using threads or an async way instead of using ajax calls!! thanks friend!

Comment: @Ikari Which of the above requests will be non-blocking? As in, I do not want my code to wait for the cURL request to finish.

Comment: Yes, how do I NOT wait for the requests to come back to finish? I just want to call the URLs and not wait for the response.

Comment: @Yourguide I haven't used PHP in ages, but you can dispatch an `exec` from your main process and just leave it be. You could probably do that with the pthreads example as well

Comment: @Yourguide I do have a trick which is to set the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS to 500, so i wait just 0.5s for the request, of course that run longer will timout, but thats not an issue since their url were executed anyway, i just dont want to wait and pause php execution.