# Execute PHP code after AJAX data is returned

Tags: php, ajax

An AJAX request is made, and PHP echoes some data which is then returned when the PHP has finished execution, like HTML being echoed onto a page 'normally'.

Other than performing a second AJAX request, is there a way to continue PHP execution after data has been returned to the JavaScript? To, for example, update a database.

Comment: No, you have to perform another AJAX request.

Comment: Why wouldn't you update the database in the same ajax request that returns the data?

Comment: This isn't actually a duplicate question, and in reality, yes the php can flush the buffer and continue to run after a result has been pushed. If that's what the OP is asking for I'd be glad to answer the question.

Comment: @AuntJamaima So the users view is updated rapidly and lengthy database functions do not delay the user.

Comment: The way to do it then is to run an asynchronous cURL function from the php script that the first and only ajax request makes. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171222/async-curl-request-in-php

Comment: You may also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response