# Phpmailer and async sending email

Tags: php, asynchronous

I read some other question before ask here cause other answers don't response to my problem.

I've a custom made cms in php. For example if I insert a new payment, the script send to all admin user a notify:

```
function insert_payment() {
// CODE TO INSERT PAYMENT INSIDE MYSQL DB
$sql_payment = "INSERT INTO payments ($amount, ...) VALUES (?, ...);"
...
// NOTIFY ALL ADMINS
foreach ( $array_emails as $email ) {
   send_email_to_admin($email, $subject, $body);
  }


  // redirect to dashboard
  header("Location: " . $homepage);
```

}

This is an example of `send_email_to_admin()` function:

```
function send_email_to_admin($email, $subject, $body) {
       // return example:
       // $result = array(
       //      "Error" = true or false
       //      "DateTimeOfSent" = datetime
       //      "Email" = string
       //)
       // SAVE RESULTS IN MYSQL DB ( I need to register results to be sure email are sent without errors...table can be then seen to a specific pages under admin panel of cms)

       $mail = new PHPMailer;
       ...
       ...
       if(!$mail->send()) {
  $result = array("Error" => true, "DateTimeOfSent" => date("Y-m-d"), "Email" => $mail);
} else {
  $result = array("Error" => false, "DateTimeOfSent" => date("Y-m-d"), "Email" => $mail);
}

       $sql_result = "INSERT INTO SentResult ("Error", "DateTimeSent", "Email", ...) VALUES ( $result['Error'], $result['DateTimeOfSent'], $result['Email'] )"
       ...
       //end function
}
```

Now if I have 1 or 2 admins is ok...but if I have a lot of admins the time gap is not good for waiting a result for each sent.

I'd like to pass the foreach loop to a child process if it possible that can process async the entire loop of SENDING and SAVING inside MYSQL the results.

So `header("Location: " . $homepage)` can be executed immediately.

Some additional info:

1. I'm using hosted server so i can't install packages and libraries
2. I can use only function provided by default PHP config
3. I can't use a cronjob queue method cause my hosting not provide a free service
4. i'd like a solution working on IIS windows server and a Linux based server

I'd like an little script example based on my code cause i never used a async method in php and i don't know nothing about it :(

Sorry for my english

Comment: is the email the same to each admin? If so just send one email with all the different email addresses in the "to" field

Comment: no... $body is personalized for each admin. but this is only an example... my goal is to implement an async delivery method in all case. i don't search for a workaround for using phpmailer using multiple address at the same time...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171222/async-curl-request-in-php might help, with or without the cURL part. Also https://blog.programster.org/php-async-curl-requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could implement a queue and process this queue (asynchronously) with a curl call.

Instead of sending the emails directly from function `send_email_to_admin()`, insert a new dataset in a dedicated SQL table `EmailQueue`. Next you write a recursive function that processes this queue (all emails waiting to be send) until the table `EmailQueue` is empty.

insert payment:

```
...
// NOTIFY ALL ADMINS
foreach ( $array_emails as $email ) {
   queue_email($email, $subject, $body);
}

curl_process_email_queue();
...
```

make CURL call, to detach from parent script ([source](http://davenewson.com/posts/2012/methods-for-asynchronous-processes-in-php-5-4.html)):

```
function curl_process_email_queue() {
  $c = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url/send_queued_emails.php);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  // Follow the redirects (needed for mod_rewrite)
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);         // Don't retrieve headers
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);          // Don't retrieve the body
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // Return from curl_exec rather than echoing
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);   // Always ensure the connection is fresh

  // Timeout super fast once connected, so it goes into async.
  curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1 );

  return curl_exec( $c );
}
```

queue email:

```
function queue_email($email, $subject, $body) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO emailQueue ("email", "subject", "body") VALUES ($email, $subject, $body)";
    ...
};
```

seperate PHP `send_queued_emails.php` script to be called via URL by cURL, that actualy sends the queued emails (recursively, until queue is empty):

```
<?php

// close connection early, but keep executing script
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/141026/5157195
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
echo('Some status message');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Encoding: none");
ob_end_flush();
flush();
// connection is closed at this point

// start actual processing here
send_queued_emails();

function send_queued_emails() {
    // avoid concurrent access
    $sql = 'START TRANSACTION'; 
    mysqli_query($sql);

    // read one item from the queue
    $sql = 'SELECT "id", email", "subject", "body" FROM emailQueue LIMIT 1';
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);

    // if no more datasets are found, exit the function
    if (!$result || (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0))
      return; 

    // mail the queried data
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    ...

    // optionally write the result back to database
    $sql_result = 'INSERT INTO SentResult ... ';
    mysqli_query($sql);

    // delete the email from the queue
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM emailQueue WHERE "id"=...';
    mysqli_query($sql);

    // commit transaction
    $sql = 'COMMIT'; 
    mysqli_query($sql);

    // recursively call the function
    send_queued_emails();
};
```

To improve the reliability you may want to use [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), to prevent issues for concurrent calls of the script `send_queued_emails.php`. For other options also see [Methods for asynchronous processes in PHP 5.4](http://davenewson.com/posts/2012/methods-for-asynchronous-processes-in-php-5-4.html).

EDIT: added "close connection early, but keep executing script" as proposed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/141026/5157195). This should enable you to even set a higher timeout for the cURL call.

EDIT2: added `header("Content-Encoding: none");` as proposed by itajackass (refer to comments)

Comment: Wow this is a great answer. I'll try it on my localhost. I don't know now if in my hosting server cURL is available so...tell me if is a good idea to insert a check like if( function_exists('curl_version')) . If is true, do your method posted. If false...continue using my original script... Is it good to prevent any compatibility?

Comment: @itajackass I think you can tell if curl is available by looking at the phpinfo() for the server

Comment: Klee, can you clarify where the async part of this is? cURL in PHP is not async by default

Comment: @ADyson yes I can visually do it...but if I use a variable check...i can write a "universal" script work for both situation...is not true?

Comment: @ADyson, as the cURL call timeouts after 1 second, it then gets detached from the the calling script (if cURL call did not complete before).
Please refer to the mentioned article for more details and other options: http://davenewson.com/posts/2012/methods-for-asynchronous-processes-in-php-5-4.html

Comment: @klee500 I see mentioned article...i think is necessary also header("Content-Encoding: none") to prevent a gzip enabled option

Comment: Hi, this is me @itajackass with my other account. I tried the script but unfortunately the script never run "send_queued_emails()". It stop before. If I comment //ob_end_flush() and //flush() the script go until the end....

Comment: Hi, i solved the problem. It was only a typing error PHP not show in the recursive script! Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using a database to store the data, is it not possible to send those data with POST in the cURL request?

Comment: @user2192013: sure you could post this data via cURL instead of "caching" it in a database. However, this approach might be a security issue, as `send_queued_emails.php` would then act like an anonymous mail relay (if the URL is reachable from the internet, it could be used to send SPAM).