# Php fetch json api for each request non-blockingly, while api server returns after 5 seconds?

Tags: php, json, rest, nonblocking

I want to fetch JSON from a remote server API, but the data returns minimum after 5 seconds. While waiting for that, if I get another user request can PHP also send/ fetch the second request to remote server. (I don't want to wait until the first data fetching is done)

**Note, that the remote server can handle multiple requests at a time. The only problem we are facing is that the process takes minimum 5 seconds.**

Comment: Use async requests then. Google for `ajax` if it is a website. Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171222/async-curl-request-in-php

Comment: Unfortunately, it must be server side. can curl maybe a solution for that?

Comment: or `pThreads`, check the post what I've copied.