# How to call asynchronous request in PHP ? Because I want return data without having to wait response of that request

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have a request to create data that has a lot of images, so I want to make one more request to download those images without having to wait for the request to finish.
I have learned about fsockopen but it doesn't support https request. Hope you will help me, thanks so much.

Comment: Use ajax for async request

Comment: I'm working on the server side.

Comment: I have an api to process db crud and in this api i want to call another api to download image but i don't want to wait for this api to finish because it takes a long time

Comment: Seems answered before, please see whether it helps: [Async_Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171222/async-curl-request-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make asynchronous HTTP requests in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124462/how-to-make-asynchronous-http-requests-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

[Developers can program synchronously, just like traditional PHP but benefit from the performance of asynchronous IO that is provided by coroutines](https://www.swoole.co.uk/docs/modules/swoole-coroutine)

You can try swoole.